# Ionic fixed css (ios/android)

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I want to create a chat application, the template is based on this [design](https://static.raymondcamden.com/images/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/shot33.png)

I already created the disscution css in a list, now what I would like to do is creating a fixed div at the bottom for text input and send button.

I encountered two problems :

1)  The div cannot be fixed in the  `</ion-content>`

```
ion-content {
    margin-top: 2px !important;
    margin-bottom: 60px !important;
}

.chat-message {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.chat-message label{
    width: 73%;
    float: left;
}

.chat-message label input{
    width: 73%;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 20px !important;
    height: 10% !important;
}

.chat-message button{
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


    <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Text here..">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-outline button-small button-positive">
        Send
      </button>
    </div>
```

2) A problem with OS compatibility :

Tabs are on the top on Android, and in the botton on IOS, so when I fixed the `div` out of  `</ion-content>`, it's shown above (margin bottom)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content>
It has height auto so you should not place your div here.
I would suggest you to put it in 
<ion-footer>
It will remain in footer always without fixing height of content.
```

Comment: but it hides tabs in IOS

Comment: increase height of footer and then put tabs and "Type here div " using grid or what you want.

Comment: I "fixed" this by changing the position of tabs. `tabs-top` attribute changes the position of tabs to the top, so I can do whatever I want on the bottom

Comment: great you make it .